# How to call "dotnet new" in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

What I want is creating a new Winforms project using [dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new), and I have tried the following code but not worked.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
//psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
//psi.Arguments = @"/C cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test & dotnet new winforms –n Test1";
psi.FileName = "dotnet.exe";
psi.Arguments = @"/C dotnet new winforms –-name Test3";
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
```

[image]

In addition, how to specify the location of the new project, such as `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test`？

Comment: When you write "dotnet new" into a command prompt, "dotnet" is the exe and "new" is the arg. What you've done there is "dotnet /C dotnet new" - a hangover from when you tried CMD? ProcessStartInfo can specify the [working directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_WorkingDirectory) too

Comment: @CaiusJard I also tried "new winforms ---name Test3". But none of them worked.

Comment: Three hyphens in the name arg?

Comment: What does "none of them worked" mean? They set your computer on fire?

Comment: @CaiusJard What is "Three hyphens in the name arg"?

Comment: You commented `---name`, and `-` is a hyphen, and you write three of them

Comment: @CaiusJard It is a typo. I used two `-`, not three...

Comment: That's why I asked.. on the Internet we can only know what you tell us, and if you tell us wrong then we either question it or assume it's the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Process p = Process.Start("dotnet", "new winforms --name Test3 --output C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test");
```

[Process.Start with arguments Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_)

[Dotnet new documentation for the -o |--output flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new)

Also make sure that you are running with the right permissions to access the folder.

Comment: I have tried this before, but it will also prompt an error. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Cleptus This has nothing to do with "--name". According to the documentation, we can know that "--name" and "-n" are equivalent.

Comment: You have the `--name` in your solution. I just did not change it. I don't understand the comment,

Comment: Can you share the output of my solution? Is it the same but for the `--name`?

Comment: The above comment is not a reply to you. Yes, the only difference is that "-n" is replaced by "--name"

Comment: Facepalm. The root of the problem lies in a wrong symbol. Anyway, I will mark this answer.